# MFMailComposeViewController Crash on device 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposer

Why is this crashing only on on a device with 8.2? on other versions works just fine and even on simulator with 8.2 works fine...

```
var mailPicer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailPicer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailPicer.setCcRecipients(["bla@dad.com"])
    mailPicer.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    mailPicer.setSubject("I have something to tell you")
    mailPicer.setMessageBody("bla bbla`", isHTML: true)
    self.presentViewController(mailPicer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am not getting any log for the crash as well...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Access the crash logs on your device from the Xcode Devices window and see what the crash dump tells you.

Comment: well I must be slow today :) this is the log
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x1823b6530 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x1933400e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   UIKit                          0x186edb0cc -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3376

Comment: As I said before slow today.... Sorry for the post I didn`t check
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`

Answer (score 0):

add this before executing the rest of your app:

```
if(!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
    // show user a message f.e.
    return
}
```